# Convert an r dataframe to correct format to use rep

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

I have a data frame of the form

```
A = data.frame(c(1485,1486,1701,1808))
names(A) <- c("ID")
```

and a second data frame of the form

```
B = data.frame(1:12)
names(B) <- "value"
```

I want to be able to use this with `rep` to form a second column in B such that I have

```
B$new <- rep(A,each = 3, length.out = 12)
```

giving

```
> B
   value  new
1      1 1485
2      2 1485
3      3 1485
4      4 1486
5      5 1486
6      6 1486
7      7 1701
8      8 1701
9      9 1701
10    10 1808
11    11 1808
12    12 1808
```

this works fine if I define `A = c(1485,1486,1701,1808)` , but because A is a dataframe it does not.  How do I convert A into the correct form to use with rep?  I have tried as.list, as.vector, as.integer unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `A` is a dataframe, you need to specify which column you want to repeat. (here `ID`)

```
B$new <- rep(A$ID,each = 3, length.out = 12)
B

#   value  new
#1      1 1485
#2      2 1485
#3      3 1485
#4      4 1486
#5      5 1486
#6      6 1486
#7      7 1701
#8      8 1701
#9      9 1701
#10    10 1808
#11    11 1808
#12    12 1808
```

In your case, this would also work without using `length.out` argument

```
rep(A$ID,each = 3)
```

It would repeat every `ID` in `A` 3 times giving the same result.

Comment: Or `cbind(A[rep(seq_len(nrow(A)),each=3),,drop=FALSE], B)` if you have an `A` containing any number of columns.

Comment: Definitely! This could be a separate answer altogether. Just out of curiosity, what does `drop = FALSE` do? Does it drop the column name?

Comment: It stops the selection from dropping back to a vector, and retains the `data.frame` format.

Answer (score 1):

```
If A is a data frame you can use rep function in this way

A = data.frame(c(1485,1486,1701,1808))
names(A) <- c("ID")

B = data.frame(1:12)
names(B) <- "value"


B$new <- sort(unlist(rep(A,times=3)))

print(B)
  value  new
1      1 1485
2      2 1485
3      3 1485
4      4 1486
5      5 1486
6      6 1486
7      7 1701
8      8 1701
9      9 1701
10    10 1808
11    11 1808
12    12 1808
```